# Share other Tweets on Facebook

Tags: facebook, twitter, sharing

I have a friend of mine that posts nice quotes on Twitter. His tweets are then automatically posted also on his Facebook account.

Under his posts on Facebook I don't have a share option like for common Facebook posts so I cannot share quotes with my FB friends. (None one of them uses Twitter.)

**Why there's no share option? Is there a workaround?**

Comment: What app is he using to post tweets on Facebook?

Comment: @Bibhas: he linked his FB account in Twitter profile checking _Allow Twitter to post on my dashboard_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook has designed apps to act this way

It's a long standing bug that has been this way for quite some time https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/164888633588257

You are going to have to click through to your friend's Twitter profile and grab the link

It should look like this

https://twitter.com/#!/Drake/status/195337215600111616

And appear on Facebook as,

[image: Twitter link on Facebook]

Hopefully a better application will come around that can be clever with this bug.

Comment: Thanks, searching around seemed no one ever complained about this...

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting ALL of his tweets to be posted to your Facebook profile?

If so, or if you want to only post tweets based on a keyword, check out [ifttt.com](http://ifttt.com) (if this then that). You can automatically post across many different social platforms automatically.

You can get your friend's Twitter RSS timeline:

> http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/USER_ID.rss
>
> Where USER_ID is the Twitter id of the username you want to subscribe.

Simply input their timeline RSS into the RSS "this" on ifttt.com, then connect your Facebook profile in "that".

I use this method for multiple automated tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There is now a much easier way go about this.

[SHAREABLE TWEETS](http://2FB.ME) lets you put a Facebook share link on your tweet that will share that specific status to Facebook. That tweet is "shareable" to Facebook.

Steps:

1) Click the timestamp on the tweet to get it's detail

2) Put 2fb.me before  URL I.E > (https://2fb.me/https://twitter.com/shareU/status/936789197456777217)

3) Put this link on a tweet, the link is shareable to Facebook.

---

ref: http://2fb.me